# How to parse substring values from a string in the service response using groovy script

Tags: regex, parsing, substring, soapui

Following is a string within an xml tag of the response for a service call.

[CDATA[name=test&username=testaccount&nonce=SL9Z4N03VANY3B5&sharedkeyid=testsystem&auth-expiresby=1410288394751&auth-algorithm=HMACSHA256&auth-signature=tPYLciqNxcEyjHygZ5mBo5qH6q+THhXKu8lyej213Fg=]]

I wish to capture values of 'auth-expiresby' & 'auth-signature' and use them as parameter values for my next service call.

Answer (score 0):

Is this good enough?

```
\[CDATA\[.*?auth-expiresby=(\d+).*?auth-signature=(.+?)(?:&.*)?\]\]
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pB4hO0/3)

---

It looks for content between `[CDATA[` and `]]`. Then it captures 1+ digit after `auth-expiresby=` and 1+ characters after `auth-signature=`. There is potentially more data, so we optionally match `&` followed by more information before closing out the `\]\]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Java problem, just chose a way to break up the string.

```
def source = '''
[CDATA[name=test&username=testaccount&nonce=SL9Z4N03VANY3B5&sharedkeyid=testsystem&auth-expiresby=1410288394751&auth-algorithm=HMACSHA256&auth-signature=tPYLciqNxcEyjHygZ5mBo5qH6q+THhXKu8lyej213Fg=]]

'''
def authExpiresby
def authSignature

source.split('&').each {

    def tokens = it.split('=')

    if(tokens[0].equals('auth-expiresby')) {
        authExpiresby = tokens[1]
    }

    if(tokens[0].equals('auth-signature')) {
        authSignature = tokens[1]
    }
}

assert authExpiresby.equals('1410288394751')
assert authSignature.equals('tPYLciqNxcEyjHygZ5mBo5qH6q+THhXKu8lyej213Fg')
```